# lxde quits unexpectedly

Tags: linux, desktop, gentoo

I use lxde on Gentoo.

Versions of software:

```
lxappearance 0.5.2
lxde-common 0.5.5
lxde-icon-theme 0.5.0
lxinput 0.3.2
lxmenu-data 0.1.2
lxpanel 0.5.12
lxrandr 0.1.2
lxsession 0.4.6.1
lxsession-edit 0.2.0
lxshortcut 0.1.2
menu-cache 0.4.1
```

Time to time lxde exits from session to the session manager (I use slim-1.3.5). After it items reboot and halt disappear from the Logout menu and ck-list-sessions shows two sessions: one active and one not active.

System log near the problem: http://vpaste.net/zOZFl

The question is where can I try to look for the reason of this problem? Where does lxde store logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old for errors. It may be the X server that is restarting. Failing that, try starting X from the console using startx. You'll need to stop /etc/init.d/xdm first. If it still boots you out, you'll probably see some useful output. As a side note, I found slim to be a little unreliable but it's been a while since I tried it. I use lightdm now instead.